# Downcast from ITableViewCell? to UITableViewCell only unwraps optionals

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview

how can i fix this problem?thanks
 that is an tableviewcell error,i didnt understand the problem.please help me.
I have an error like Downcast from ITableViewCell? to UITableViewCell only unwraps optionals,did you mean to use'!'?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

   var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as?UITableViewCell

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    let film = self.filmler[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    let filmAdi = film["ad"]! as! String
    cell!.textLabel!.text = filmAdi

    return cell!;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this line in you code

```
var cell:UITableViewCell?  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
```

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns an optional type UITableViewCell. So you need not to type cast

```
public func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// you need to maintain one space between ? symbol and UITableViewCell as follows , it will work
var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell
```

Comment: if you use like this then it will work . var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell

Comment: In your code you didnt maintain any sapce(as?UITableViewCell) , so it is showing error if u maintains space(as? UITableViewCell) ,error will be remove